# Shortest distance from z-axis to given lines

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry, solid-geometry

The shortest distance between the lines $x+y+2z-3=2x+3y+4z-4=0$ and the z-axis is?. $$\text {Attempt} $$. I first took the cross product of the vectors of two lines ie $i+j+2k,2i+3j+4k $ to get the perpendicular  vector as $-2i+k $. I know that distance between two skew lines is $|\frac {(a_2-a_1). (b_1×b_2)}{(b_1×b_2)}| $. Where $a_2,a_1$ are position vectors from lines and $b_1,b_2$ are the vectors $-2i+k,k (z-axis) $.But how to find the position vectors ?.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=t$.

Hence, $x+y=3-2t$ and $2x+3y=4-4t$, which gives $x=5-2t$ and $y=-2$.

Thus, $(5-2t,-2,t)$ is our line.

Now, let $(5-2t,-2,t)\subset\pi$ and $(0,0,k)||\pi$.

Let $\vec{n}(a,b,c)$ is a normal of $\pi$.

Thus, $(a,b,c)(0,0,1)=0$ and $(a,b,c)(-2,0,1)=0$ or $c=0$ and $-2a+c=0$,

which gives that $\vec{n}(0,1,0)$ and the equation of $\pi$ it's
$y=-2$.

Id est, the distance is $2$.

Comment: I didn't get the last line, and the equation of pi it y=-2.. how did you relate y with distance .

Comment: @Archis Welankar The distance between $z$-axis and the plain $y=-2$ equal to $2$. It's obvious, but we can use:  distance$=\frac{|ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$, where $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is an equation of the plain and $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is a point. In our case a point it's $(0,0,0)$ and the plain it's $0x+y+0z+2=0$.

Comment: Oh thanks completely missed this formula.